# Renormalize a repo's entire history without making a new commit/changing history in any other way

Tags: git

I need to renormalize entire repo's history line endings from CRLF to LF in all files except .ics, .jpg and .png

Is it possible to do this with .gitattributes without making a new commit and having the history preserved (except all the line endings being changed)

Do I have to use rebase -i to go commit by commit, and If I do, what is the easiest way to modify these commits (I have 20 of them)

Any other way that could help me? I am using Windows, Git Bash.

Comment: Are you prepared that the history will be rewritten and there will be new commits with different IDs (hashes)? If yes — you can try automate interactive rebase with *something* like `git rebase --exec "git add --renormalize ."`

Comment: that would be a case for `git filter-repo`

Comment: History *is* commits. You're proposing to change the contents of every commit. That's a new, different history. There is no getting around this: if you want to renormalize everything, you must replace the old repository with the new and improved one. (Though with just 20 commits, this seems like a pretty small problem.) Filter-branch or filter-repo is the way to automate this.

Comment: The question title is contradictory. Change one bit of the first commit (whether content or metadata) and the entire history is different.

Comment: @RomainValeri The entire question is contradictory, not only the title. "Is it possible to change all commits *having the history preserved*?"